# Update VirtualStringTree header after a component property has changed

Tags: delphi, collections, components

I would like to create a component named `TMyComp`.
This component has associated following properties:
`property VirtualStringTree: TVirtualStringTree` and 
`property Columns: TMyCompColumns` as a collection of items.

The columns from my component are the same with the header columns from associated VirtualStringTree.

What I would like to do, is to redraw at design-time the header text from VirtualStringTree when the caption is updated.

My problem is that I don't know how to trig the `procedure RedrawVirtualStringTreeHeader` because it's not known by class `TMyCompColumns` or even `TMyCompColumnsItem`.

```
TMyCompColumnsItem = class(TCollectionItem)
  private
    FCaption: String;
    function GetPosition: Integer;
  protected
    function GetDisplayName: String; override;
    procedure SetIndex(Value: Integer);
  public
    constructor Create(Collection: TCollection); override;
    procedure Assign(Source: TPersistent); override;
  published
    property Caption: String read FCaption write FCaption;
  end;

  TMyCompColumns= class(TCollection)
  private
    FOwner: TComponent;
  protected
    function GetOwner: TPersistent; override;
    function GetItem(Index: Integer): TMyCompColumnsItem;
    procedure SetItem(Index: Integer; Value: TMyCompColumnsItem);
    procedure Update(Item: TMyCompColumnsItem);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent);
    function Add: TMyCompColumnsItem;
    property Items[Index: Integer]: TMyCompColumnsItem read GetItem write SetItem;
  end;

  TMyComp = class(TComponent)
  private
    FColumns: TMyCompColumns;
    FVirtualStringTree: TVirtualStringTree;
    procedure SetMyCompColumns(const Value: TMyCompColumns);
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property Columns: TMyCompColumns read FColumns write SetMyCompColumns;
    property VirtualStringTree: TVirtualStringTree read FVirtualStringTree write  FVirtualStringTree;
  end;

...

function TMyCompColumnsItem.GetDisplayName: String;
begin
  Result:= FCaption;
  RedrawVirtualStringTreeHeader; //<--- procedure not recognized!!!
end;

...

procedure TMyCompColumns.Update(Item: TMyCompColumnsItem);
begin
  inherited;
  //RedrawVirtualStringTreeHeader; ???or here
end;

procedure TMyComp.RedrawVirtualStringTreeHeader;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  if Assigned(FVirtualStringTree) then
    begin
      FVirtualStringTree.Header.Options:= FVirtualStringTree.Header.Options + [hoVisible];
      FVirtualStringTree.Header.Columns.Clear;

      if FColumns.Count > 0 then
        for i := 0 to FColumns.Count-1 do
          with FVirtualStringTree.Header.Columns.Add do
            begin
              Text:= FColumns.Items[i].Caption;
              //...
            end;    
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching, this is the answer:

1. The trigger of `RedrawVirtualStringTreeHeader` has been done through the `FOwner` inside of `TMyCompColumns` class.

`procedure TMyCompColumns.Update(Item: TCollectionItem);
begin
  inherited;
  (FOwner as TMyComp).RedrawVirtualStringTreeHeader;
end;`

2. I updated `property Caption: String read FCaption write FCaption` with `write SetCaption` and I add the procedure

`procedure TMyCompColumnsItem.SetCaption(const Value: String);
begin
  FCaption:= Value;
  Changed(False); //---> this will trigger TMyCompColumns.Update 
end;`

**In fact the secret was `Changed(False);` that trig the `Update`**

Thanks also to open source of `TVirtualStringTree` component.